# Is this a Proper WLAN Fragmentation Diagram I made?

Tags: packet-analysis

I took information from several images and compiled it into one and am wondering if it's correct. Looking at the smallest components of the packet -> fragments -> frame would this diagrammatically/logically be correct?

[image]